# How to implement dict-like `get` method?

Tags: python

I have my own data structure and I want to implement `mystructure.get(id)` the way it works in `dict`.

If no `default` argument is passed, it should raise `self.NotFound` exception. The problem is that I can't tell whether the `default` has been omitted or `None` has been passed.

If there is no object with `id==48`

```
mystructure.get(48)
```

Should raise `NotFound`

```
mystructure.get(48, default=None)
```

Should return `None`

Do you know how to differentiate between the two?

```
class MyStructure:
    ...

    def get(self, _id, default=None):
        ...
```

The only thing that comes to my mind (and is very dirty):

```
def get(self, _id, default="173095fb-da18-4bab-b943-2f51c327f7cb"):
    ..._id not found in this structure...
    if default=="173095fb-da18-4bab-b943-2f51c327f7cb":
        raise self.NotFound
    return default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by generating your own unique object and using it instead of `None` as the default argument value.

```
class MyStructure:

    NUL = object()
    class NotFound(Exception): pass

    def get(self, _id, default=NUL):
        if default is self.NUL:
            raise self.NotFound(f'{_id=}')
        print('OK')


inst = MyStructure()
inst.get(13, None)  # -> OK
inst.get(42, -1)    # -> OK
inst.get(48)        # -> __main__.NotFound: _id=48
```

**Comment**

It seems little strange to raise a "not found" error when an argument with a default value was left off. Why are you even providing a default value if it can't be omitted?

Comment: The default value basically toggles the method between `__getitem__` and `get`.

Comment: I was deciding on how to make it work and I decided to go the dict way. But now I realized it's not `dict.get` but rather `getattr` that behaves this way.

Comment: I see...well, learning that you can create your own unique objects in order to distinguish them from `None` is generally a useful technique to know about.

Answer (score 0):

You could also assign a simple error string and if `None` is not passed to it, raise the error... like this

```py
def get(self, key, default = "Not Found"):
        if default is not None:
            raise self.NotFound(f'{key}')
```